# Using loaddata to add a ManyToOneRel into a django models class

Tags: python, django

I have an .xml file with country and continent data, which looks like this

```
<object model="countrydata.continent" pk="7">

<field name="name" type="CharField">South America</field>

<field name="code" type="CharField">sa</field>

</object>


<object model="countrydata.country" pk="1">

<field name="name" type="CharField">Andorra</field>

<field name="capital" type="CharField">Andorra la Vella</field>

<field name="code" type="CharField">ad</field>

<field name="population" type="PositiveIntegerField">84000</field>

<field name="area" type="PositiveIntegerField">468</field>

<field name="continent" rel="ManyToOneRel" to="countrydata.continent">6</field>

</object>
```

The first object is to a continent, the second one is to a country. I'm trying to build models for them so that I can use manage.py loaddata command to parse through the .xml, but I'm having trouble with the ManyToOneRel -part.

My models.py is

```
from django.db import models


class Continent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='')
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='')



class Country(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='')
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='')
    capital = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='')
    population = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    area = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

, but I'm not sure what I need to add to Country in order to be able to read the

```
<field name="continent" rel="ManyToOneRel" to="countrydata.continent">6</field>
```

line. I tried fiddling around with foreignkey and manytoonerel, but got neither of them working.

Latest attempt example:

```
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
```

and I get the error "Country has no field named 'continent'", so it leads me to believe that I'm establishing the model field in a wrong way, but I'm not sure how I need to establish it.

Edit:

```
class Continent(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='')
code = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='')


countries = models.ManyToManyField(
    'Country',
    through='Country',
)

class Country(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='')
code = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='')
capital = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='')
population = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
area = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

group = models.ForeignKey(Continent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

gives me the error

> ERRORS:
>   countrydata.Country: (fields.E336) The model is used as an intermediate model by 'countrydata.Continent.countries', but it does not have a foreign key to 'Continent' or 'Country'.

which means that I probably can't use foreignkey as the way to read it?

Comment: How was this XML generated?

Comment: I was given it beforehand, so it's static

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the difference to my earlier attempts this one had, but

```
continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent, default='', related_name='countries')
```

seems to work.